# What are the Amazon Kindle User Agent strings?

Tags: user-agent

What are the valid Amazon Kindle User Agent strings?

Are they different for each model of the kindle?

**Update:** 
just got this one off the new wi-fi only kindle:

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; en-US) AppleWebKit/528.5+ (KHTML, like Gecko, Safari/528.5+) Version/4.0 Kindle/3.0 (screen 600x800; rotate)

Answer (score 2):

From [Marco Arment](http://www.marco.org/35457408):

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Linux 2.6.10) NetFront/3.3 Kindle/1.0 (screen 600x800)

From other research, Amazon increments the `Kindle/n.0` version number depending on the Kindle version (i.e., the Kindle 2 is `Kindle/2.0`).

#### Edit

From [Device Atlas](http://deviceatlas.com/devices/Amazon/kindle+2/entry/1292350), currently valid UA strings are the following:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Linux 2.6.10) NetFront/3.4 Kindle/1.0 (screen 600x800)
>
> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Linux 2.6.22) NetFront/3.4 Kindle/2.0 (screen 600x800)